# How to use two or more time picker in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using 2 date picker at the same page.. thats called From time and To time. now its works only one time picker. another one timepicker is not working.. i mean From time is working, but To time is not working.. can you tell me what is my mistake..

Fiddle: [My code is here](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/n06pqLjm/)

here is my code..

```js
/* FRom date */
var timepicker = new TimePicker('time', {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'dark'
});
timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {

  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
  evt.element.value = value;
});

/* To date */

var joe = new TimePicker('sample', {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'dark'
});
joe.on('change', function(e) {

  var value = (e.hour || '00') + ':' + (e.minute || '00');
  e.element.value = value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div>From time:
    <input type="text" id="time" placeholder="Time">
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>To time:
  <input type="text" id="sample" placeholder="Time">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you link to the documentation of the timepicker.js library you use ?

Comment: @xTrimy yes i already linked `timepicker.min.js`

Comment: The documentation please, not the library itself.

Answer (score 2):

you can initialize something like below if both the functionalities are same which seems to be working based on your fiddle

```
/* FRom date */
var timepicker = new TimePicker(['time', 'sample'], {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'dark'
});
timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {

  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
  evt.element.value = value;
});
```